How to update the specific package to a desired version (in an Nx project)?
I want to learn what is the best approach for updating a package version in an Nx project, because updating it directly seems to produce a handful of issues with depending packages.
To be more precise, I am working on an Angular project within Nx workspace, and wanted to update the eslint package from 8.48.0 to 9.0.0 - I ran the npx nx migrate eslint@9.0.0 command and package.json was updated:
IMG - package.json
But after running the npm install command, I got the following error:
IMG - error output
So there are multiple "eslint" related packages depending, and I want to know what is the correct way to handle the upgrade in this situation?
